# How to add target to button in tableview header section

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

So I have a table view with 2 headers, having one button each.
I want to know which button of header is tapped, how would I achieve that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.dashboardScreenHeader

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 11, y: 12, width:170, height: 18)
    titleLabel.text = headerSection[section]
    titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(16)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("See All", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.customBlueColor, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 303, y: 14, width: 62, height: 12)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    view.addSubview(button)

    return view
}

@objc func showDetail(){
    print("button tapped")
}
```

I tried passing section in this show detail button but getting an error

I want to achieve this in showDetail function

See All button in section 1 tapped -> do x

See All button of section 2 tapped -> do y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.dashboardScreenHeader

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 11, y: 12, width:170, height: 18)
    titleLabel.text = headerSection[section]
    titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(16)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("See All", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.customBlueColor, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 303, y: 14, width: 62, height: 12)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    button.tag = indexPath.section

    view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    view.addSubview(button)

    return view
}

@objc func showDetail(_ button:UIButton){
    switch button.tag{
    case 0:
        //code for section 0
     case 1:
        //code for section 1
     default:
        //default code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by assigning **tag** to each button and checking for the same tag in button action like this:

In your viewForHeaderInSection method:

```
button.tag = section
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail:), for: .touchUpInside)
```

button action:

```
@objc func showDetail(sender: UIButton!) {
  if(sender.tag == 0){
  //first button tapped
  }else if(sender.tag ==1){
  //second button tapped
  }
  .....
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign tag to each button you have created in `viewForHeaderInSection`.

```
button.tag = section
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail:), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And then

```
 @objc func showDetail(_ button:UIButton){
    switch button.tag{
     case 0:
        // code for section 1
        // Do your X
     case 1:
        // code for section 2
        // Do your Y
     default:
        //default code
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewForHeaderInSection` assign `tag` to the button,

```
button.tag = section
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail:), for: .touchUpInside)

func showDetail(sender: Any?) {
  guard let button = sender as? UIButton, let tag = button.tag
  if(tag == 0){

  } else if(tag == 1){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could customize headerView, in headerView file, customize style.
"dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView" can optimize code and mermory.